# Can I set the HTML dir attribute using CSS

Tags: html, css, hebrew

I am dealing with some Hebrew text that includes a few English words separated by commas. The HTML display is incorrect, and I am trying to see if it can be fixed with CSS or if I need to adjust the text with a direct HTML attribute.

An example of how the text comes out natively:

```css
.rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body dir="rtl">
  <h4>Incorrect (no special styling)</h4>
  <p><em> ל-Space, Time ו-Energy</em></p>
  <h4>Correct</h4>
  <p><em> ל-Space<span dir="rtl">, Time</span> ו-Energy</em></p>
  <h4>CSS doesn't work</h4>
  <p><em> ל-Space<span class="rtl">, Time</span> ו-Energy</em></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Does anyone know if this can be accomplished with straight CSS?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. The issue is that the text is being entered by a Translator and being pulled into my site. I'm trying to give them a simple tag to enter (like `<rtl>`) that I can style with CSS, rather than having the linguists coding themselves to get the correct text output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need [`unicode-bidi: isolate;`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-writing-modes-3/#unicode-bidi) as well.

```css
.rtl {
  direction: rtl;
  unicode-bidi: isolate;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body dir="rtl">
  <h4>Incorrect (no special styling)</h4>
  <p><em> ל-Space, Time ו-Energy</em></p>
  <h4>Correct</h4>
  <p><em> ל-Space<span dir="rtl">, Time</span> ו-Energy</em></p>
  <h4>CSS does work now</h4>
  <p><em> ל-Space<span class="rtl">, Time</span> ו-Energy</em></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.